# Merge [cq5] into [aem] tag

Tags: discussion

I'm following both tags and 90% of the questsions have them both on it. As the product officially is called Adobe Experience Manager [aem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aem) since version 5.6 it would in my eyes make sense to deprecate [cq5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cq5) and only have [aem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aem) left; or at least have a synonym link. Though for the later I don't have enough reputation to officially suggest a synonym.

Comment: *Both* of those tags should be burninated and replaced with non-acronym versions.

Comment: Even with the necessary privileges, as `cq5` has the number "5" in it's name, the system considers it a version-specific tag and will only let moderators link it as a synonym. Would be happy to see an non-acronym tag, but either way we shouldn't have two tags because the product had a marketing change.